# Having issues trying to animate an electric and magnetic field of a moving point charge

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, animation, physics, visualization

I'm currently trying to plot an electric and magnetic field using Mathematica, but I'm quite new to the program and I've run into a wall.

I start out with a moving point charge, and this is what I've done:

```
Z[d_,w_,t_] = d Cos[w t]
z = {0,0,Z[d,w,t]}
V[d_,w_,t_] = D[Z[d,w,t],t]
v = {0,0,V[d,w,t]}
A[d_,w_,t_] = D[V[d,w,t],t]
a = {0,0,A[d,w,t]}
```

Which gave the output

```
d Cos[t w]
{0, 0, d Cos[t w]}
-d w Sin[t w]
{0, 0, -d w Sin[t w]}
-d w^2 Cos[t w]
{0, 0, -d w^2 Cos[t w]}
```

I tried to make it so I could input any direction into the code, in case I wish to see how the fields interact with other examples.

Then, I made another point in perspective to the observer

```
R =  {0, 1/2, \[Sqrt]3/2}

accel = a - (a.R)*R
```

My electric field,

```
Elec[d_, w_, q_, r_, t_] = -((q accel)/(4 \[Pi] Subscript[\[Epsilon], 0] r c^2))
Subscript[\[Epsilon], 0] :=  8.85*10^-12
c := 3*10^8
```

My magnetic field,

```
B[t_] = R \[Cross]Elec[d, w, q, r, t]/c
```

This is where I get stuck. What I want to do is move my particle of velocity (v) and acceleration (a) from `t = 0->tmax` through a 3D space. As the particle moves, it should emit the electromagnetic waves from it. Exactly how this picture shows

[image: EM wave]

The way I'm trying to do it is like this:

1) Use something like Graphic3D or Plot3D to get a point in a 3D graph.

2) Give the point a direction and a path (make it into a vector in the calculated path)

3) Animate the point generated from part 1 in a straight line at velocity and acceleration calculated above with respect to time.

4) Animate the electric & magnetic fields being emitted from the particle with respect to the particle's path and time.

Would anyone be able to help me with the steps I've listed above? I would need help especially with step 4, as I am not even sure what function I can use to animate that part of the animation. If there is an easier way to do this of course, please feel free to show me as I'm still trying to learn all the functionality of this program!

EDIT: What I've tried to do to make the animation work.

This is the velocity vector of my particle

```
Animate[Plot[V[1, 1, t + l], {t, 0, 10}], {l, 0, 10}]
```

My Electric Field

```
Animate[Plot[Elec[1, 1, 1 , 1000, t + l], {t, 0, 10}, 
PlotRange -> 0.0000000001], {l, 0, 10} ]
```

My Magnetic Field

```
Animate[Plot[B[1, 1, 1 , 1000, t + l], {t, 0, 10}, 
PlotRange -> 0.0000000000000000003], {l, 0, 10} ]
```

My current issue is that I'm not sure how to merge these three 2Danimation into one 3D animation. My electric field is also broken apart as two waves of different direction instead of one in between the two directions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, people who wan to helo you will have do a lot of work to reproduce your problem so they can experiment with possible solutions.