# Merging two 2D wave animations into one 3D animation?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, animation, physics

I have an electric field,

```
Elec[d_, w_, q_, r_, t_] = -((q accel)/(4 \[Pi] Subscript[\[Epsilon], 0] r c^2))
Subscript[\[Epsilon], 0] :=  8.85*10^-12
c := 3*10^8
```

Where `accel` is a vector shown as below

```
{0, 1/4 Sqrt[3] d w^2 Cos[t w], -(1/4) d w^2 Cos[t w]}
```

This is how my output looks:

[image: Elecfield]

This is how my animation looks

```
Animate[Plot[Elec[1, 1, 1 , 1000, t + l], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> 0.0000000001], {l, 0, 10} ]
```

[image: elecanimate]

I want to make it so that I get one single wave to show up, but in 3D. The wave should be the average of the two in both magnitude and direction. I was wondering what function or set of functions I could use to achieve my goal?

Another question if i  may,
I have a magnetic field,

```
B[d_, w_, q_, r_, t_] = R \[Cross]Elec[d, w, q, r, t]/c
```

Where R is:

```
R =  {0, 1/2, \[Sqrt]3/2}
```

Here's a picture of my code

[image: Magneticfield]

How can I made this into a 3D wave from my current animation?

```
Animate[Plot[B[1, 1, 1 , 1000, t + l], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> 0.0000000000000000003], {l, 0, 10} ]
```

[image: Animation]

These waves are all travelling in the Z direction, with the Magnetic wave propagating in the X and the electric wave between Y,Z.

My ultimate goal is this picture, but animated

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can these be a set of points ? You could discretize it and then make a line out of them according to what you are wanting.

Comment: Also, welcome to mma.SE! Check out our [Code of Conduct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/conduct). This is a great question, but I would like to make some edits to show you better syntax to use (using [SetDelayed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) versus [Set](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html), for example). I'm working to answer it, but I do not think that your graphic properly represents what you want to show?

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211451/having-issues-trying-to-animate-an-electric-and-magnetic-field-of-a-moving-point

Comment: @MichaelE2 that is an actual duplicate, wow! chaelim should merge the two if they can, perhaps?

Answer (score 9):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[t_] := Sin[t];
f2[t_] := Sin[3 t];

Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{{t, f1[t], 0}, {t, 0, f2[t]}, {t, 0, 0}}, {t, 0, tmax},  
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Gray}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3 Pi}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {2.5, -1.3, 2}], {tmax, .1, 3 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
frames = Table[ParametricPlot3D[{{t, f1[t], 0}, {t, 0, f2[t]}, {t, 0, 0}}, {t, 0, tmax},  
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Gray}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 3 Pi}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    ViewPoint -> {2.5, -1.3, 2}], {tmax, .1, 3 Pi, 3 Pi/100}];

Export["anim.gif", frames]
```

[image]

You can embellish the content styling the lines as tubes and showing additional elements:

```
ClearAll[show]
show[tm_] := Show[ParametricPlot3D[{{t, f1[t], 0}, {t, 0, f2[t]}}, {t, 0, tm},  
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Tube[.05]], 
     Directive[Green, Tube[.05]]}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.03], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 3 Pi}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   ViewPoint -> {2.5, -1.3, 2}], 
  Graphics3D[{ Opacity[.2, Red], EdgeForm[], 
    InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}], Green, 
    InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}] , Opacity[1], 
    Black, Thin, InfiniteLine[{{0, 0, 0}, {3 Pi, 0, 0}}]}]]

Animate[show[tmax], {tmax, .1, 3 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
frames = Table[show[tmax], {tmax, .1, 3 Pi, 3 Pi/100}];
Export["anim.gif", frames]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one! OP's plot specifications are a little weird (to me) I can't parse out what is time and what is whatever else. I hope they can answer, else this is a good method to follow, @chae-lim

Comment: Hey!
Thank for this! Another quick question if you don't mind answering: If you see my electric field and magnetic fields? they have very small values. When I plug my wave functions into the code you've showed me, the wave is not even visible. I can change the range of the graph, but I am not able to change the Zoom. I was wondering if there was a function for that?

Comment: @chaelim, try  changing `PlotRange -> {{0, 3 Pi}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}` to `PlotRange -> {{0, 3 Pi}, All, All}`.

Comment: The usual way to handle this is to change units---multiply all equalities by 4πε and plot (4πεE) against time.

Comment: Thank you both! I got it working.

Comment: @chaelim can you show us what you ended up with? I know I am curious!